# вывести текст со стилями

Tags: jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток, есть ajax скрипт который после выполнения выводит текст, но никак не получается выделить один элемент например жирным шрифтом

```
if (response === 'email error') {
    $("span#err").text("письмо на E-mail: <b>1@1.com</b> не отправлено").css({"color":"orange"});
}
```

Как HTML теги использовать в данном коде?

Comment: может [`$(...).html(строка_с_html_тегами)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: diraria, спасибо помогло)